# Differences between non-convex and convex optimization problem with l0-Norm Regulization

Tags: convex-optimization, nonconvex-programming, minlp, cutting-planes

I'm currently in the process of writing my bachelor's thesis and trying to deal with the theory behind the model in this paper [Risk-calibrated Super-sparse Linear Integer Model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.00168) (Berk Ustun and Cynthia Rudin).

In this paper, the author stated that normal Cutting Plane Algorithm often **stall** while solving a non-convex MINLP-Problem with an objective function (in easier form): $$ V(\lambda) = log(1 + exp(-\langle\lambda, y_i x_i \rangle) + C_0 \cdot \Vert \lambda \Vert_0$$ with $\lambda \in \mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}\subset \mathbb{Z}^d$ and users can specify for example $\lambda_j \in \{-5,\dots,5\},\forall j \in [d] $. I have read papers about the [big-M-assumption](https://hal.science/hal-01254856/document) and also have the idea of transforming the hard $\ell_0$-Norm into extra linear binary variables in the original MINLP-Problem:
$$V(\lambda) = log(1 + exp(-\langle\lambda, y_i x_i \rangle) + C_0 \sum_{j = 1}^{d}\alpha_j$$
$$s.t. \lambda \in \mathcal{L}, \vert\lambda\vert \leq 5\cdot \alpha, \alpha \in \{0,1\} $$
Up to this point, I would expect that the MINLP is convex (since the objective function is now the sum of convex functions and the constraints are all linear), and by replacing the logistic loss function with a linear variable $l$ and adding a new linear constraint $l \geq \hat{l}^k(\lambda)$, with $\hat{l}^k(\lambda)$ as the cutting-plane approximation of the logistic loss with $k$-cuts, the approximated MILP would still be convex?

I'm currently stuck at this point.

Comment: The question spans five lines on my screen and doesn't match the title of the post. Can you clarify what you are asking for?

Comment: @HenrikAlsingFriberg Thank you for your reply. I realized that my questions were poorly formulated. I'm having trouble understanding whether the MINLP with objective function $V(\lambda)$ with a $\ell_0$-regulization can be see as a convex problem, since I can transform the $\ell_0$-Norm in additional constraints as stated above. I apologize for my bad english again!